# Perforce p4 interchanges equivalent in git

Tags: git, perforce

I am looking for [p4 interchanges](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_interchanges.html) equivalent in git. Is there any option/flag for finding the changes which are in one branch yet to be integrated/merged to another branch.

I am looking for this option to track if changes done in my feature branch are yet to be merged into master branch before I can cut a release branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How about using **`git cherry`**?

> **`git cherry [-v] [<upstream> [<head> [<limit>]]]`**
>
> - outputs the SHA1 of every commit between `<limit>` and `<head>`,
> - and prefixes a **`-`** to commits in the list that have an equivalent in `<upstream>`
> - and prefixes a **`+`** to commits in the list that do not have an equivalent in `<upstream>`

*where `<upstream>` and `<head>` refer to git branches

and `<limit>` refers to a commit in the history of the git repository.*

---

In a situation where a `topic` branch consisted of three commits,
and the maintainer applied two of them to `origin/master`, the situation might look like:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --boundary origin/master...topic
* 7654321 (origin/master) upstream tip commit
|
* cccc111 cherry-pick of C
* aaaa111 cherry-pick of A
|
| * cccc000 (topic) commit C
| * bbbb000 commit B
| * aaaa000 commit A
|/
o 1234567 branch point
```

Now `git-cherry` will show a concise summary of what is yet to be applied to `origin/master`:

```
$ git cherry origin/master topic
- cccc000... commit C
+ bbbb000... commit B
- aaaa000... commit A
```

Here, we see that the commits `A` and `C` (marked with a **`-`**) are already cherry-picked into `origin/master`, while the commit `B` (marked with a **`+`**) is yet to be merged into `origin/master`.

> When we have 2 local branches X and Y to be compared;
>
> To ask the question:
>   **Are there any commits in branch X that are NOT yet in branch Y?**
>
> we would say `git cherry branchY branchX` 
>   and look for any commits listed with a **`+`** before them.

Reference: [man page of `git cherry`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry.html).